# how to update tabView page content when device back button is pressed in flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, flutter-layout, setstate

I created a widget with three tabs. Inside a tab I change the state i.e view of the widget on click of button but when the device back button is pressed I want the tab content to be reversed to the original state. I have tried using willpopscope to detect the back button but the setstate doesn't call the tab build method to reload or reverse the original state.

Any idea would be really helpful.

Comment: please post your code here